# H.geo.LineString is not behaving like h.geo.strip

Tags: javascript, here-api, heremaps

I am upgrading here maps to version 3.1, trying draw a draggable polygon. I have replaced a few methods and now working on replacing H.geo.strip() with H.geo.lineString(). However, When I try to insert 1st point into the line string in like this -

```
_this.growingStrip = new H.geo.LineString();
_this.growingStrip.pushPoint(_this.map.screenToGeo(e.currentPointer.viewportX, e.currentPointer.viewportY));
```

Here is what gets pushed in _this.growingStrip -

```
{
"X":[]
,"a":0
}
```

But it was different when I was using H.geo.strip() as follow -

```
_this.growingStrip = new H.geo.Strip();
_this.growingStrip.pushPoint(_this.map.screenToGeo(e.currentPointer.viewportX, e.currentPointer.viewportY));
```

This was pushing a following object -

```
{"a":null,"b":[63.628684238260696,55.35862348973751,0,53.22838240102656,70.12424848973751,0],"c":0}
```

I have really tried hard to wrap my head around it but no luck.
Any help is appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

I tried with code similar to yours and all works fine. Points are pushed to the LineString correctly after each click:

```js
var growingStrip = new H.geo.LineString();

map.addEventListener('tap', (e) => {
  let cp = e.currentPointer;
  growingStrip.pushPoint(map.screenToGeo(cp.viewportX, cp.viewportY));
  console.log(growingStrip.getLatLngAltArray());
})

// after first click -> (3) [36.11458078918906, 8.356475830078125, 0]
// after second click -> (6) [36.11458078918906, 8.356475830078125, 0, -6.58685279251426, 0.1263427734375, 0]
// ...
```